# Import Export both are not responding anything both is not working

Tags: php, magento

Trying to export Magento single products but only a blank page is appearing. could not export any products either from **System ->Import/Export->Export** or from **System->Import/Export/Dataflow-profile**.

When trying to import just five products from **System ->Import/Export->Import** and by choosing a file to import when I click on "check data" button, file is just loading but it doesn't respond any thing, neither it generate any error/warning nor Import button is appearing.

I checked log file to see the error I got

```
 2014-05-08T09:33:05+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined offset: 58233  in /var/www/vhosts/Outletzon.secureserver.net/httpdocs/testdocs/app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Export/Entity/Product.php on line 873

 2014-05-08T09:47:41+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():     </catalog_product_view>  in /var/www/vhosts/Outletzon.secureserver.net/httpdocs/testdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 444
 2014-05-08T09:47:41+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():                            ^  in /var/www/vhosts/Outletzon.secureserver.net/httpdocs/testdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 444
 2014-05-08T09:47:41+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 104: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document  in /var/www/vhosts/Outletzon.secureserver.net/httpdocs/testdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 444
 2014-05-08T09:47:41+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():       <catalog_category_default>  in /var/www/vhosts/Outletzon.secureserver.net/httpdocs/testdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 444
 2014-05-08T09:47:41+00:00 ERR (3): Warning:      ^  in /var/www/vhosts/Outletzon.secureserver.net/httpdocs/testdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 444
```

Answer (score 0):

Try SYSEM  [IMPORT/EXPORT]--> [DATAFLOW - PROFILES]--> [Export All Products]
This is more better to output all data.

Comment: I tried with this way also but it keep loading and finally loading stop with a blank page but nothing got exported.